# Service now oauth grant flow error with oauth_token.do

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I follow the article [OAuth authorization code grant](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/administer/security/concept/c_OAuthAuthorizationCodeFlow.html) flow to get tokens

Initially I made request:

```
dev234.service-now.com/oauth_auth.do?response_type=code&client_id=****534e4e81b7f
```

and the response after allowing access to:

```
http://callback-url?code=Z2YYGhgfh1tMoFPDO7Dr0nZuPnhQPs53qwkm_Sw99gpUf92gU3x_OOuoOqdYBvlPFF01pOfgZg9VoXpCruSRYQ
```

after that to get token:

```
dev234.service-now.com/oauth_token.do?grant_type=authorization_code&code=<***>&client_id=<***>&client_secret=<***>
```

When I did request this, throwing error

```
{"error_description": "access_denied","error": "server_error"}
```

Can't I get `access_token` and `refresh_token` in json format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last worked,
after getting code from earlier steps,i made a php request looks like::

$client = new Client();

```
   $post_data = [
                   'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                   'code' => 'your code',
                   'redirect_uri' => '<callback_url>',
                   'scope' => 'useraccount'
               ];

   $auth = base64_encode('<client_id>:<client_secret>');

   $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://myinstance.service-now.com/oauth_token.do', [
       'headers' => [
           'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $auth,
           'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       ],
       'form_params' => $post_data
   ]);

   dd(json_decode($res->getBody(), true));
```

The response contains accesstoken and refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

Check step two

> https://myinstance.servicenow.com/oauth_auth.do?grant_type=**code**&code={the auth code}&redirect_uri={the_same_redirect_url}&client_id={the_same_client_identifier}

you are using

> grant_type=authorization_code

Comment: Tried it too,but no change

Comment: make sure you have run it again as the authentication code you were given has probably expired they are extremely short lived.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,if i use "https://myinstance.servicenow.com/oauth_auth.do?.." response would be like "https://ca1511e1.ngrok.io/servicenow/redirecturl#access_token=xxxxxxx"
is it not possible to get in json format..